# Why does ".Remove" affect all the items in a 2D structure assigned with a list?

Tags: vb.net, oop, console-application

I'm currently trying to create a Sudoku Solver, and on the step of assigning some possible values to a box that is not already preoccupied. (Bit of background info for why I'm doing this shebang: Sudoku is a number game based on a 9x9 grid, its contextual rules allow certain boxes in the grid that are not preoccupied to hold possible values during the process of solving )

To do this I created a structure, defined it as two dimensional, and populated it with a predefined list of integers using a for-loop.

Now when I tried to remove one integer from the list of a particular item in the two dimensional structure, I found out that all the lists of the items in the structure have had that integer removed. There's probably a simple solution to this, but I've been really struggling to find it. Hope the code below clarifies the somewhat confusing verbal explanation.

```
Structure Element
    Dim PossibleValues As List(Of Integer)
    Dim ElementValue As Integer
End Structure

Sub Main()
    Dim List as New List(Of Integer)({1,2,3})
    Dim TDP(8,8) as Element
    For x as integer = 0 to 8
        For y as integer = 0 to 8
            TDP(x,y).PossibleValues = List
        Next
    Next
    TDP(0,0).PossibleValues.Remove(1)
End Sub
```

Now I expect only TDP(0,0) would have a list of "2,3" when print out its list of integers, but when I check other items , i.e. TDP(1,0), its list is of integer is also "2,3"

Comment: You only have one List!  Each instance of your `Element` structure (which should really be a class) refers to the same instance of the list.  To fix this, move the creation of the list _inside_ the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the assignment here:

```
 TDP(x,y).PossibleValues = List
```

`List(Of T)` is a reference type, so this assigns a reference to the *same List object* to each of the array elements.

If you want each item to have it's own list of possible items, you need to either *deep copy* the list or create a new list:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim TDP(8,8) as Element
    For x as integer = 0 to 8
        For y as integer = 0 to 8
            TDP(x,y).PossibleValues = New List(Of Integer)({1,2,3})
        Next
    Next
    TDP(0,0).PossibleValues.Remove(1)
End Sub
```